# Float to integer conversion acting super weird in Python

Tags: python, debugging, floating-point, integer, type-conversion

So this just wasted a couple of hours of mine in debugging..

```
a,b = 32980.642295,32630.642295
print a-b
print int(a-b)
print int(a) - int(b)
```

Output :

```
350.0
349
350
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on? Why wouldn't the int of 350.0 just be 350? I assume python is doing some weird stuff in casting a and b before converting to int..

EDIT/ Update :

```
x = a-b
```

Value stored in x is now 349.99999999999636 not 350.0

This might help future people coming to the post [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` implicitly applies `str()` to the things it's asked to print, and in Python 2 `str(some_float)` rounds to 12 significant digits.  `repr(some_float)` rounds to 17:

```
>>> a,b = 32980.642295,32630.642295
>>> print str(a-b)
350.0
>>> print repr(a-b)
349.99999999999636
```

So that's why.  `a-b` is actually a little less than 350.

In Python 3, `str(some_float)` and `repr(some_float)` both produce the shortest string `s` such that `eval(s) == some_float`:

```
# Python 3 here, not Python 2
>>> a,b = 32980.642295,32630.642295
>>> print(str(a-b))
349.99999999999636
>>> print(repr(a-b))
349.99999999999636
>>> eval(str(a-b)) == a-b
True
```

Comment: I googled around and found out what ( I think) is the issue. It's not print for me, as I was storing the value in a variable and accessing it later, but its the way floating point math is handled. I just used print for the example here, my bad. 

This helped my understanding  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#

If I make x = a-b and then check x, it will give me 349.99999999999636

Comment: It makes no difference at all whether you use `a-b` directly or store it in a variable first.  The computed value is exactly the same either way.  The reason your output was `350.0` is as already explained:  `print` in Python 2 _rounds_ the displayed value to 12 significant digits.  It doesn't matter one whit whether you do `print a-b` or `print x`.

Answer (score 2):

`print` rounds floats more aggressively than you might expect on Python 2. `a-b` is very slightly lower than 350; `print` rounds this to 350, but `int` truncates the number to 349.

Answer (score 0):

well, it is my understanding that in the first case your result if a float, which means it print the .0;

in the second case, it does the subtraction operation with float numbers, and than rounds it to the nearest integer;

in the third case, it rounds both values to the nearest integet, and than does the subtraction;

hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Floating math isn't broken. Due to conversion to (machine internal) binary representation, small errors are introduced depending on the size of internal number format. Thats the reason the result is a bit smaller than 350 as we calculate from the decimal numbers.

In the first line that result is **rounded** to 350, in second line the int() just **truncates** to 349.

The third line behaves differently and delivers by chance the result 350 because truncation changes both values in the same direction.